# OS X Get string from standard system localized strings

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, localization

I need to use a few strings in my project like a "Cancel", "Battery", "Apply", etc.

It is possible to get localized strings from **system localized** strings?

Example:
If OS language is German I need to get german-localized strings for my strings above.

Comment: There's no way to get exactly what you're asking for. Among other things, there's not necessarily exactly one translation for any given term in English. It can depend on the context. (As a strained example, "battery" can mean criminal physical contact, as in assault and battery.) Apple provides [glossaries](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=glossar) of translations used in the OS and its apps. The format is for the relatively obscure AppleGlot tool, but you could process them into a first pass for your own translations. Always have a human translator review them, though.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, likely it's impossible. You need to localize all strings yourself, besides for example "Back button" or someone like that in iOS. UIKit has some amount of localized strings, but you don't have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps:-

1) Go to the Project Setting->Build Settings->Localization

2) Click on + button and choose German and then click on Finish button

3) Create new String file name as Localizable string (cmd+N)

4) Now inside that just add the key value like that below:-

[image]
5) Now wherever you want to display your value just access it like that using code:-

For example, you want to display in the textfield.

```
self.txt.stringValue=[NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"cancel", nil)];
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's not what I need, please check updated question.